# NPM Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, bower

I have an ionic application and am currently using both `NPM` and `Bower` as package managers. I would like to consolidate to only one, `NPM`.

However, I am unable to find an ionic framework package. I can only find the CLI (`npm install ionic`). Is there a front-end ionic package with `NPM`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ionic-framework` equivalent for `npm`. As alternative approach you could install `ionic-framework` directly from `GitHub`:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/driftyco/ionic.git
```

**Note:**

The command above installs `Ionic2`, if you want `Ionic v1` you have to add the target version explicitly, e.g.:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/driftyco/ionic.git#v1.3.1
```

Comment: exactly the alternative I was looking for. Did not realize you could install directly from GitHub, thanks